# calling shared object crashes at the second time

Tags: c++, c, dll, shared-libraries

I have created a ".so" file and invoked from my code. It works very well for the first time, and I am getting the desired result, whereas when the same so is invoked for the second time its getting crashed. The below is my code. Am I doing anything wrong.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h> /*for printf() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit() */
#include <FaceRecognition.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*pf)( string, string, string );

int func ()
{
 void *lib;
 pf greet;

 const char * err;

    lib=dlopen("/home/libh.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (!lib)
    {
     printf("failed to open hello.so: %s \n", dlerror());
     exit(1);
    }
    dlerror(); /*first clear any previous error; redundant 
               in this case but a useful habit*/
    greet= (pf) dlsym(lib, "sample");/*locate hello() */

    err=dlerror();/*check for errors and copy error message*/
    if (err)
    {
     printf("failed to locate hello(): %s \n", err);
     exit(1);
    }

    greet( "auth", "/home", "/home/train1.gal" ); /*call hello() */

    dlclose(lib);

 return 0;
}


int main () {
    func();  --> getting the expected result for the first time
    func();  --> getting crashed here ( core dumbed)

}
```

Comment: might be that the dll doesnt unload properly

Comment: @Paranaix how to unload it? Does dlclose wont do this?

Comment: I mean that the dll code itself is buggy and doesnt deinitialize properly if unloaded, thats just a guess

Comment: Compile everything with `-g3 -o0` and use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

```
lib=dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "/home/libh.so", RTLD_NOW);
```

if you want to load the same shared library multiple times.
Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745975/load-multiple-copies-of-a-shared-library)

Comment: If I use "dlmopen" its crashing for the first call itself.

Comment: @user3021933 But in general I think he's right. You cannot load your DLL twice. `dlclose()` doesn't unload it IIRC, it just relases the current process from accessing the loaded image.